# What's the 'Frequent' sort function?

Tags: support, questions, sorting

What is the function of the ['Frequent'](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) sorting option on the Questions tab?

Comment: Roughly, the questions listed earlier are those that have more pages on-site linking to them. But I don't know more exactly than that, so am posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @msh210, alright, I'll take my question over to meta.SO.

Comment: In theory you should get answers here also: SE is insistent that the sites' Meta sites are just as good. (And if you post a bug report or feature request here, and it's not something that's already been dealt with at MSO, then the mods here are supposed to call it to SE staff members' attention.) De facto, though, more people who will know an answer or have suggestions will see it on MSO. So in general it might be wiser to ask there. In this case, I'll be glad to advertise your question among some other SE people and see if it gets any answers -- unless you've asked on MSO already. Have you?

Comment: ...Ah, I see you have. Re-asked at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172726.

Comment: @msh210 <slaps own wrist> I already asked over there (and got an answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you then asked [the same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172726) on Meta Stack Overflow, I'll quote [Oded](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/497/oded)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172728) from there so this doesn't stay unanswered:

> When many questions are closed as a duplicate of one specific question, that question is a "Frequent" question - that is, it has been asked, in different guises, frequently. In addition, if the question is linked to from another question, it is one of the "Frequently" linked to questions.
>
> In essence the sort is for questions that have been linked to often within the site.
>
> If you hover over the tab, the tooltip is "questions with the most links" - that is, with many  questions linking to it.